# Where to set the S3 configuration in Spark locally?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I've setup a docker container that is starting a jupyter notebook using spark. I've integrated the necessary jars into spark's directoy for being able to access the S3 filesystem.
My Dockerfile:

```
FROM jupyter/pyspark-notebook

EXPOSE 8080 7077 6066

RUN conda install -y --prefix /opt/conda pyspark==3.2.1
USER root

RUN (cd /usr/local/spark/jars && wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/3.2.1/hadoop-aws-3.2.1.jar)
RUN (cd /usr/local/spark/jars && wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bundle/1.12.213/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.213.jar )

# The aws sdk relies on guava, but the default guava lib in jars is too old for being compatible
RUN rm /usr/local/spark/jars/guava-14.0.1.jar
RUN (cd /usr/local/spark/jars && wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/29.0-jre/guava-29.0-jre.jar )

USER jovyan

ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXX
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXX
ENV PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --no-browser"
ENV PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/opt/conda/bin/jupyter
```

This works nicely so far. However, everytime I'm creating a kernel session in jupyter, I do need to setup the EnvironmentCredentialsProvider manually, because by default, it's expecting the IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider to deliver the credentials which obviously isn't there. Because of this, I need to set this in jupyter everytime:

```
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "com.amazonaws.auth.EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider")
```

Can I configure this somewhere in a file, so that the credentialprovider is set correctly be default?

I've tried to create ~/.aws/credentials to see if spark would read the credentials by default from there but nope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of browsing the web, I found the correct properties (not in the official documentation though) that were missing in the spark-defaults.conf:

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider com.amazonaws.auth.EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider
```

Answer (score 0):

s3a connector actually looks for s3a options, then env vars, before IAM properties
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Authenticating_with_S3

something may be wrong with your spark defaults config file

Comment: In my spark-default.conf wasn't anything configured regarding S3. The answer for my problem was setting up the spark-defaults.conf. I didn't found the correct parameter names in the aws-hadoop config, since there they focus on building everything in xml/maven. I'll post the answer here: